# How to Implement stack data type inside a structure for a linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

We are to make a video store program, but I've been stuck in "RENT A VIDEO" and "RETURN A VIDEO" because I have to use stack in the processing.
My main idea is basically whenever a customer rents, the video ID rented will be pushed in to the customer node stack data type. Same goes to returning a video, it will pop() the returned video ID from the customer node stack data type.
(I am not sure if I am supposed to use linked list or if it's the best way around.)

```
struct customerNode
{
    int customer_ID;
    string name, address;
    stack <string> rentedVid;
    stack <string> tempRent;
    struct customerNode* next;
};
struct customerNode* first = NULL;
struct customerNode* last = NULL;

void insertCustomer(int custID, string custN, string custA)
{
    struct customerNode* temp;
    temp = new customerNode;
    temp->customer_ID = custID;
    temp->name = custN;
    temp->address = custA;
    // stack rentedVid ??
    // stack tempRent ??

    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}
```

(I also have a linked list for the video ID, title, copies and etc.)
I am not confident with my program actually.
The requirement:
You must store your customers in a queue (i used linked list for now, but will change it later) when you retrieved them from the text file. They must also be stored in a queue during processing. Saving back to the text file will be done when the user chooses Exit Program.
Rented videos will be stored in a stack and will be saved in the CUSTOMER-RENT text file when the user chooses Exit Program.

Comment: The stack should only be useful for internal operations, 100% under the control of the application, like, for example, and undo/redo list. Not for operations that depend on external features, like a customer.

Comment: That's what I thought too. It's just that our professor is requiring us to implement this. Although, we are actually required to use queue for the Customer not linked list.

Comment: Maybe the learning effect is supposed to be that if you use the most unsuitable container type your program might get complicated. Wierd way of teaching....

Answer (score 1):

If it's a business application the stack might not be the best option. what if customer wants to rent multiple videos and not return them in order?

cpp's [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a better option to store all of the user rented videos and search/delete them. linked list is also a good data structure the main benefit of linked list is it's suitable if you delete/insert elements in the beginning and end, not for random access.

Comment: Even if I use queue (requirement by professor) for the customer id, name, and address, stack wouldn't be the right application for the videos rented, right? Apparently, even I still don't think that stack will actually work or the right data structure to use.

Comment: You are right, stack limits user to rent and return videos in the same order, and that's not how renting video works. I once had a DS class sometimes instructors just for the sake of using some DS they require you to implement it and there is no reasoning behind it.

Comment: Your comments are unclear. Normally, customers rent and return videos in the same order (or, any order they like to...). But stack requires them to return them in *opposite* (LIFO) order.